# Can I use proportions as continuous independent variables in a regression?

Tags: logistic, proportion, odds-ratio, compositional-data

I was assuming I can until I come across the concept of compositional data. Now I'm confused. My DV is a binary outcome, my IVs are proportions, say: A, B, C where A+B+C=1. I was going to run a logistic regression of DV on A B, as if treating C as the reference category in a logistic regression of DV on an IV with 3 categories. And I was also thinking I can interpret the odds ratios the same way. Has anyone read a paper that use such approach? If so, can you kindly post the reference? Thanks.

I read a little about compositional data analysis and am not sure I understand it. For one thing, my IVs can be zero, so I can't do log ratio transformation unless adding a small arbitrary constant. But even if I do so, how do I interpret the result? And how come I can't use the original proportions as IVs but once transformed it's ok? Anyone can explain it in simple language? Thanks so much!

Edit:
Here's an example of my data:

Y   A   B   C

1  0.5 0.1 0.4

0  0.6  0  0.4

1  0.2 0.3 0.5

0   1   0   0

...

Sunny

Comment: Yes, there is some confusion here and unfortunately it makes it hard to determine what you're really trying to do.  Could you tell us in what sense you are viewing *proportions* as "categories"??

Comment: My independent variables (IVs) A B C are % in one of the 3 categories (a b c).

Comment: If the data is compositional (sometimes called "mixture" data e.g. blending together 3 different fruit juices), then you don't need to transform the independent variables. However, you do need to take into account the equality constraint, that is, the fact that your **k** factors (or components) are not independent since setting **k**-1 of them determines the % of the last one. You should be able to use logistic regression to model the binary outcome, but you'll want to adjust the model for the equality constraint. Look into Scheffe and/or slack polynomials for mixture data.

Comment: Thanks so much MAB. I've found some literatures on the mixture data and will read. Meanwhile if I could collapse my independent variables into two: A vs B+C. Can I fit a logistic regression of Y on A without adjusting for any constraint? The question here is if proportion of A has an effect on the outcome. Thanks again.